# How to grab content of @section('title')

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have written a static file based page management system which relies upon each page being a blade template of the following structure:

```
@extends('en/frontend/layouts/page_section')
{{-- Page Title --}}
@section('title')
Current Page Title
@parent
@stop

{{-- Page content --}}
@section('pageContent')
...
@stop
```

So that I can make a drop down with links to all pages within this section I would like to grab just the content within `@section('title')`.

I know that this is possible, I just do not know how.

Please advise, thank you.

**edit** For clarification, I am wanting to load the view into my controller and grab the value of section title such as in the following pseudo-code

```
Class Controller{

    // would return string 'Current Page Title' for above example
    public function getTitle($viewSlug)
    {
        $view = View::make($viewSlug);
        return $view->section('title');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way of using View or even the blade engine directly to return just the content of a section. Therefore I decided the ugly brute force method was the only way left and as this is just being used in a flatfile => db converter it is only being run a few times a year so speed was not a requirement.

```
function getTitle($viewSlug)
{
    // get path to view file
    $viewPath = \View::make($viewSlug)
        ->getPath();

    $view = \File::get($viewPath);
    // flatten view as we dont know how to use regex without this
    $view = str_replace("\n", '', $view);

    $titleRegex = "/@section\('title'\)(.*)@parent/";
    preg_match( $titleRegex, $view, $matches );
    return $matches;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your layout:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

In your view:

```
@section('title', 'Your title here')
```

Comment: Ah, I noticed the confusing language in my question. I have edited it with clarification. What I need to do is grab the content of @section('title') as defined in the view, through some mechanism in the controller. That way my copywriters can edit just text view files and I can run my import command to update the database with page titles, etc. Thanks.